# Errors regarding Jdk5 in intellij even though pom.xml explicitly sets source to 7

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have opened a maven project in Intellij (14.1.4 Ultimate) and the JDK is not being recognized.   When attempting to run one of the programs the following error occurs - and in any case the file has a bunch of "red"s in it when viewed in the IDE:

```
Error:(55, 50) java: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
```

This is strange because the normal settings are in place to use java7:

In `pom.xml`:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

In the project - JDK level is set to 7:

[image]

Likewise in the Module:

[image]

But we get all sorts of issues when attempting to compile (even after reimporting maven projects):

[image]

Note: this project does build/run on command line using maven.

Also note: I have already tried blowing away the Intellij project and rebuilding from scratch. No change in behavior.

**Update**  The following is a result of following (accepted) answer from @Peter Lawrey. We can see that the jdk got mysteriously set to 1.5. I have updated it to 1.7 manually.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes IntelliJ gets confused though I don't know why.  The setting you need is

```
File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler
```

Find your module and change it to version 1.7 instead of 1.5.

I have projects with many modules and the same parent pom which sets this and sometimes just one of the many modules will think it's 1.5 when the rest are 1.8. i.e. the same configuration across many modules.

Comment: How many different places to look for this stuff in IJ .. ;)  Yes that is what happened: says 1.5

Comment: @javadba I don't understand the purpose of this screen and why is it not part of the module/project settings !? IntelliJ didn't always have it AFAIK, and it only causes problems for me.